# Send (Load) a URL to web browser and run it in background in APEX

Tags: apex, visualforce, docusign

Does Apex/Visualforce allow a URL which is stored as string in apex and run it in web browser in background.

Actually, that url is returned from a Docusign RestAPI callout for posting the envelope into "correction" status. The Envelope correction Status is not activated until i manually paste the url (link) in to a web browser and run it.

Does anyone know how to run a url programatically in a web browser through Apex/Visualforce in background ?
(or) Is there anyway that i could activate the "correction" status of envelope in Docusign other than running the URL in web browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [HttpRequest](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) class directly from Apex to make a GET request to the given URL. This would be equivalent to what the browse does. The only difference would be if the browser sends a specific cookie, which can also be replicated in Apex if you have the required cookie value.

You will need to add the domain in the remote site settings as well.

Comment: Thanks. I have used the "GET" method already and status code is returned as  302 ("Found"). But the correction status of Docusign envelope is still not activated. (It only activates if i manually paste the return url in browser as of now).  Any thoughts? @Daniel Ballinger

Comment: @sam_s If you get a 302 (Status: "Found"), you have to follow it through, as it is a redirect code. One of the headers for such a redirect will be "Location" (`response.getHeader('Location')`). If you get a redirect, go to the next Location, sending the same payload as the first request. You'll want to set a redirect limit so you don't run into limits.